# Web development in LAMP VM WARE

Tags: php, ftp, vmware, lamp

I have a LAMP configuration set up in  a VM WARE. I am going to transfer files via FTP using transmit client.

Currently I have my files in the following directory

192.133.323.122/website/project/home.php

Do I create a folder in a specific directory?

Comment: what's your question? as it stands, it's not much use ...

Comment: Yes let me rephrase my question. I want to develop a website using a LAMP environment that I have currently set up in my VM ware. In what file path or directory shall I create or use to save all my php, html, css files..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it'll go in your

```
your_user_here/var/www
```

but it doesn't matter really, as long as you know where it is and you know how to reach it.

I would suggest creating a folder with the name of the site, so you can find it easily, so it'll be something:

```
your_user_root/var/www/project_name
```